# How to extract vertex , face from .stl file

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt5, numpy-stl

I'm currently working on a project which use PyQt5 to be able to display 3D object using `opengl.GLViewWiget`

I have already download a .stl file and a base of PyQt5 module

```
self.Widget3D = opengl.GLViewWidget(self.centralwidget)
self.Widget3D.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1000, 100, 351, 271))
self.Widget3D.setObjectName("Widget3D")
```

I have a problem with .STL file I have install `numpy-stl` and read through its document but haven't really find a way to extract it and use with `GLMeshItem`
as far as I find is this example code

```
#Extract vertex points and face faces from the STL file.
points, faces = self.loadSTL(filename)

meshdata = gl.MeshData(vertexes=points, faces=faces)
mesh = gl.GLMeshItem(meshdata=meshdata, smooth=True, drawFaces=False, drawEdges=True, edgeColor=(0, 1, 0, 1))
self.viewer.addItem(mesh)
```

The `self.loadSTL` part is unclear for me for how to really use the `numpy-stl` in this code

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that should allow you to create the `GLMeshItem` from an stl file. This isn't *exactly* what you're asking, since I'm not extracting the vertices and faces from the stl. But you don't actually need to do that; the `GLMeshItem` constructor can take a Nx3x3 array of vertices (where each of N triangular faces is specified by three len-3 arrays), and this is exactly what numpy-stl gives you when you load an stl from file.

```
import numpy as np
import stl

my_mesh =  stl.mesh.Mesh.from_file('my_stl_file.stl')
face_clr = np.array([[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5]] * 3] * np.shape(my_mesh.vectors)[0])
mesh_item = gl.GLMeshItem(vertexes=my_mesh.vectors,  # Nx3x3
                          faceColors=face_clr,  # Nx3x4
                          drawEdges=True,
                          smooth=False)
```

If you did want to extract the vertices and faces separately, I believe you'd just have to do some manual manipulation of `my_mesh.vectors`. Ie, find all unique vectors in `my_mesh.vectors`, and figure out which faces include which unique vectors.